# Как показать, скрыть блок на PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Хочу "показать", "скрыть" блок `<div>` на php c помощью mysql, в общем чтоб сохранял и запоминал значение "показать" или "скрыть". Спасибо.

Comment: И в чем проблема?

Comment: Дык не знаю как? Хоть идею подайте.

Comment: Создаешь поле в какой-нибудь таблице БД типа int(1) с умолчанием 1 (показать) или 0 (скрыть) - что там по умолчанию? ) Когда строишь страницу - проверяешь значение, и в зависимости от него делаешь выбор - выводить див или нет. Ну а если значение нужно изменить - обычный апдейт. Конкретизируй задачу.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно, в принципе тоже так подумал.

Answer (score 1):

Скрыть блок div можно, используя селектор в CSS `DIV{display:none;}`,  для того чтобы заново показать  `DIV{display:block;}`. Для хранения результата в СУБД можно использовать таблицу со следующими полями: поле для идентификатора пользователя, поле с ID тэга, поле состояния. Ну и плюс ко всему придется использовать фреймворк типа jQuery или ajax для отсылки данных без перезагрузки страницы, ну или javascript.

Comment: этим способом будет тяжелей поскольку не знаю вообще ни jQuery ни ajax ни javascript